# How can I get the height of an element after it has rendered?

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to get the height after an element is rendered. The element is inside another component than which I want to detect it in.

I know I can do it like this:

```
  const heightOfStepper = document.getElementsByClassName(
    "step-indicator"
  )?.[0]?.offsetHeight;
  
  const minHeight = useMemo(
    () => `calc(${heightOfStepper}px + var(--small-spacing))`,
    [heightOfStepper]
  );
```

But when I `console.log` out the heightOfStepper, the value is `0` the first render, and if a add some code to my IntelliJ and save, then I get the real height of the stepper, since then  the stepper is already mounted.

How can I get the height of an element after it has rendered, and the component is inside another component? (So I can not just use `useEffect(() => ..., [])`)

Answer (score 0):

In react you should avoid regular DOM queries (like `getElementsByClassName`) - use `ref` instead. What do you mean you cannot use `useEffect`? You can use it even in deeply nested component. If you want to get height of parent element you will want to use [forward ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html), e.g. like this:

```
// parent component
const App = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      MyDiv
      <Child ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
};

// child component
const Child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current.offsetHeight);
  }, []);
  return <p>I'm a child component</p>;
});
```

If your find yourself in need of passing ref deep through components tree or e.g. between siblings - pass ref through context - that was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57573148/how-correctly-pass-a-node-from-a-ref-to-a-context)